# site admin viewing other sites customers

Tags: database, magento-1, customer

I have a multisite that has three separate websites using the same product database, the problem I have is the separate admins all being able to view the whole customer database, which is not ideal.

How can we limit the admins view so they can only to view the customers relevant to their website.

Answer (score 0):

It's only possible with an Enterprise Edition of Magento.

You may also search for third party extension.

Comment: Hi there.  Thank you for your expeditive reply, I have been searching high and low for a solution. All the best friend